# How to embed smart contract in website

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, native-assets, decentralized-applications, query

I am creating a dapp website and which will reward it's users on completing different tasks. I have to create cardano native tokens. My question is that how can I send, lock and burn native tokens from my website

Answer (score 2):

Many projects are using these:

- Dapp Connector Wallet
- Cardano Serialization Lib
- Plutus smart contract

Example: https://github.com/Berry-Pool/spacebudz

https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib

Answer (score 1):

I've written an example precisely for these sort of questions

https://github.com/dynamicstrategies/cardano-wallet-connector